# Что именно возвращает promise?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch, response

Изучаю тему промисов, и второй день, несмотря на все усилия, не могу добиться ясности в вопросе, что именно возвращает промис, и как с этим работать?

Пример1: функция для того, чтобы отправлять что-то на условный сервер.
Кладем в переменную функцию для получения промиса.

```
const postData = async (url, data) => {
    const res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: data
    });
    console.log(res);
    return await res;
};
```

Как я понимаю, внутри функции в res должен записываться объект Promise, (ведь его возвращает нам функция fetch). Но console.log(res) выводит в консоль объект Response.

**Вопрос 1: откуда берется Response, если fetch должен возвращать объект Promise ?**

Хорошо, Response так Response. Наверное при вызове функции я должен его и получить(раз она его возвращает). Сразу после присвоения функции смотрю, что она возвращает:

```
console.log(postData('someURL', someJSONData);
```

И она возвращает как раз объект Promise в состоянии pending.

**Вопрос 2: внутри функции мы видели что в переменной res лежит объект Response, мы возвращаем его как результат функции. Почему возвращается Promise?**

**Вопрос 3: почему этот Promise в состоянии pending? Это значит что он в этот момент выполняется? как и когда тогда получать результаты? И что он в итоге вернет?**

Дальше. VSCode и курс, который я прохожу, говорят что вместо

```
return await res;
```

стоит написать

```
return await res.json();
```

потому что тогда слово await будет иметь смысл. Это понятно. Но.

**Вопрос 4: если res у нас все таки Response, и к нему применимы методы, то что содержится в этом Response, если я просто отправляю данные на сервер? Кроме информации о статусе запроса, там что? Те самые данные что я отправил?**

окей, я применю метод:

```
return await res.json();
```

**Вопрос 5: я ведь получу очередной промис, а не данные в формате JSON. Для получения самих данных мне придется писать для этого промиса then? Как их вообще грамотно получать?**

Пример2: функция для того, чтобы отправлять что-то на условный сервер.

```
const getData = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
};
```

Моя логика такая: при вызове

```
const data = getData('someURL');
```

я получу результат работы функции res.json(), то есть промис. По моей логике, я могу получить из него данные, отдельно задав этому промису then, который задаст инструкцию в случае если полученные данные успешно получилось превратить в json:

```
let jsonData;
data.then(data => { jsonData = data; });
```

**Но в jsonData у меня оказывается undefined. Почему? и как мне получить объект JSON сразу из функции?**

И последнее. Выполняю код:

```
const getData = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    console.log(res);
    return await res.json();
};

const data = getData('someURL');

console.log(data);
```

Как я понимаю, ключевые слова async и await указывают коду, что
1 - функция асинхронная
2 - сначала мы начнем выполнять функцию, в которой выведем в консоль res, потом получим результат работы fetch, потом уже применим на нем метод json(), затем запишем его в переменную и вернем
3 - следовательно уже после этого возвращенное значение присвоится переменной data
4 - и уже после этого мы можем вывести ее в консоль

На практике же сначала работает console.log(data), выводящее объект Promise, и только потом срабатывает console.log внутри вызываемой ранее по коду функции. Почему?

За два дня я прочитал несколько статей, в том числе и на learn.javascript и MDN, и посмотрел несколько видео, понимания это не прибавило. Очень хотелось бы разобраться, но как будто в стену долблюсь. Если кто-нибудь, у кого это понимание есть, разъяснит мне эти моменты, я буду крайне рад и благодарен. Спасибо.

Comment: async/await является синтаксическим сахаром. await ожидает выполнения асинхронной функции и возвращает не промис а полученные данные

Comment: Покажите пример первого пункта, где `fetch` возвращает не промис, а Response. В консоли браузера напишите `fetch('http://example.com')` и увидите промис. Вот скрин вообще с запросом аналогичным вашему - https://i.vgy.me/NGFmJC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `fetch()` возвращает `Promise`, который разрешается в `Response`. *"Почему консоль показывает `Response`?"(с)* - понятия не имею.
- *Почему это `console.log(postData('someURL', someJSONData)` возвращает `Promise`*? - Любая асинхронная функция возвращает `Promise`.
- *"там что? Те самые данные что я отправил?"(с)* - Нет, там данные которые возвратил сервер, если конечно их туда кто-то запихнул.
- *"у меня оказывается undefined"(с)* - Значит там и не было никакого JSON. Вызов `.then(data => { jsonData = data; })` завершился ошибкой, а `jsonData`, так и осталась `undefined`. А если бы даже и не было ошибки, все равно был бы `undefined` - код ведь не останавливается на строке `data.then(...)`, а приспокойно продолжает выполняться.

Путанница, полагаю, возникла из-за того, что нет ответа "Content-Type: application/json".
Читать долго, ниже простой пример.

Если положить рядом с документом такой файл "json.json":

```json
{"a": 1}
```

... и подключить такой скрипт, все должно работать.

```js
// Если не предполагается обрабатывать ответ внутри postData
//   нет никакого смысла в async/await
//   fetch и так возвратит Promise
const postData = (url/*, data*/) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    // GET - только для теста через плагин Live Server VSCode
    method: 'GET',
    // headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    // body: data
  })
}

// Использовать await можем только в async
void async function () {
  // получаем разрешенный Response
  const res = await postData('./json.json')
  // дожидаемся чтения Response в JSON
  const data = await res.json()
  // ... и только после этого получаем результат
  console.log(data) // {"a": 1}
}()
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище, я уже в целом разобрался, но все равно спасибо за то что откликнулся)